# How to check from where job arrived in HashiCorp Nomad?

Tags: nomad

I wonder is there any way to find out how Nomad receives any specific job. As I found in logs there is information about job submit time only. But IP from which this job arrived or submit method (API, GUI) is not specified. Is there any way to find this information?

Answer (score 1):

Although I haven't tried it myself yet, but what you refer to falls under [audit logs feature](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/hashicorp-nomad-enterprise-audit-logging) of Nomad where payload is somewhat similar to Vault audit logs. Here is how audit logging [can be setup](https://www.nomadproject.io/docs/configuration/audit) as a part of Nomad server configuration, however, this is available only for enterprise version of Nomad at the moment.

Anyhow, looking at the docs I guess fields that you would be interested are

```
.payload.auth.stage
.payload.auth.accessor_id
.payload.auth.name
.payload.request.operation
.payload.request.endpoint
.payload.request.request_meta.remote_address
.payload.request.request_meta.user_agent
.payload.response.status_code.
```